# Rational analogue of expansion to base b

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof, decimal-expansion

As is well known, we can expand every positive integer $n$ to a base $b \in \Bbb N$ in the form $$n = \sum_i a_ib^i ,\ \ \ 0\leq a_i \leq b_i-1$$ uniquely.

Less well known is that we can do this for $b= c/d \in \Bbb Q^{+} \text{ with } c > d$ in the form $$n = \sum_i a_i b^i,\ \ \ 0\leq a_i < c ,\ \ \ \ c,d,a_i,n \in \Bbb N$$This expansion will not be unique in general and the proof I know of is by induction. One simply looks at the maximum value reachable by using upto $k$ terms and shows that the $b^{k-1}$ term is less than this value.

Is there a more intuitive proof that avoids computation of these results? Preferably, whatever the strategy is would prove both results at once and show uniqueness in the case of integers too.

Comment: What exactly are you claiming about base $c/d$ expansions? The coefficients $a_i$ are presumably integers? Could you elaborate on that proof by induction in light of the fact that for most choices of $a_i$s the sum will not be an integer.

Comment: $a_i$ is an integer, so is $n$. The only thing not integral is $b$ in the second form.